# Jquery Math with an HTML Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

so I have a table that's like the following.

```html
<table>
<tr><th>My Table><th class="total"></th></tr>
<tr><td class="title">title 1</td><td class="value">10%</td></tr>

<tr><td class="title">title 1</td><td class="value">20%</td></tr>

<tr><td class="title">title 1</td><td class="value">30%</td></tr>

<tr><td class="title">title 1</td><td class="value">40%</td></tr>
</table>
```

I'm wanting to calculate the sum of all td's with the "value" class (which should equal 100). I then want to divide the total of "value" (100) by the number or table rows (4) and then display the new toal (25) in the th class "total". I've tried several methods and can't figure this one out. Any help would be deeply appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can query the cells containing your values using `document.querySelectorAll` and summing up each cell, calling `parseFloat` on each cell's innerHTML, then insert the average into the total cell using querySelectorAll again. No jQuery needed.

```js
var valueCells = document.querySelectorAll('.value');
var sum = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < valueCells.length; ++i) {
    sum += parseFloat(valueCells[i].innerHTML);
}

document.querySelectorAll('.total')[0].innerHTML = (sum / valueCells.length).toFixed(2);
```

```html
<table>
<tr><th>My Table<th class="total"></th></tr>
<tr><td class="title">title 1</td><td class="value">10%</td></tr>

<tr><td class="title">title 1</td><td class="value">20%</td></tr>

<tr><td class="title">title 1</td><td class="value">30%</td></tr>

<tr><td class="title">title 1</td><td class="value">40%</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you!! One more quick question, is there any way to trim decimals to two decimal points in the total cell?

Comment: Call .toFixed(2) on the result `(sum / valueCells.length).toFixed(2)`

Answer (score 2):

You can try below code.. Hope it helps

```js
var total = 0;
//loop through all td with class value
$("td.value").each(function(index) {
  //remove the last character from the text and convert to float
  //then add it to variable total
  total += parseFloat($(this).text().slice(0,-1));
});
//divide total with (number of rows - 1)
//-1 to remove the first row which is the heading
total = total / ($("table tr").length - 1);
//assign the result to th with class total
$("th.total").text(total);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr><th>My Table><th class="total"></th></tr>
<tr><td class="title">title 1</td><td class="value">10%</td></tr>

<tr><td class="title">title 1</td><td class="value">20%</td></tr>

<tr><td class="title">title 1</td><td class="value">30%</td></tr>

<tr><td class="title">title 1</td><td class="value">40%</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

The sample way, to get desired output using [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery):

**you can have Answer with limited to 2 decimal places**

<kbd>[**Demo here**](https://jsfiddle.net/k2h1hwwh/)</kbd>

```js
var total =0, count =0;
//iterate through all tr without using index
$('table .value').each(function()
{
  //read inner html, add to a variable
  total += parseFloat($(this).html().slice(0,-1));
  //get total number of '.value'
  count ++;
});
//show avg. output in '.total' th
$('table .total').html((total/count).toFixed(2));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr><th>My Table</th><th class="total"></th></tr>
<tr><td class="title">title 1</td><td class="value">10%</td></tr>

<tr><td class="title">title 1</td><td class="value">20%</td></tr>

<tr><td class="title">title 1</td><td class="value">30%</td></tr>

<tr><td class="title">title 1</td><td class="value">40%</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @RussPowers, answer is updated with a demo, to get answer to 2 decimal places